# Stratified sampling with percentages 100x's in R

Tags: r, statistics

Hello and thank you for looking at this question.
I have three columns: User ID, Status (active or inactive) and Tenure (target or no). I want to sample 428 of these ID's 100 times (with replacement). The samples must be 77% target tenure and 23% no tenure. The end goal is to see the average percentage of active and inactive ID's for the 100 samples. I'm using R for this analysis and I'm pretty new, so far I can only get the random sampling

sample <- data[sample(1:nrow(data),428,replace = TRUE),]

Any help or ideas would be incredible, thanks so much

Comment: 77% + 33% != 100%

Comment: How about the answers at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7950834/drawing-a-stratified-sample-in-r

Comment: Woops sorry, meant to write 23 thanks!